# IdentityServer3 & External Provider Dynamically

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver3

I am implementing IdentityServer3 as an SSO platform for multiple websites (not multi-tenant however). Each website is for a separate customer whom has their own Office365 domains. We also serve in a support capacity for each customer so we have our own Office365 domain that we want to hook into IdentityServer. Setup would be like such..

=====
Customer 1 OIDC Domain: https://login.microsoftonline.com/customer1.onmicrosoft.com" 
Customer 1 Website Domain: http://mycustomer1.com

=====
Customer 2 OIDC Domain: https://login.microsoftonline.com/customer2.onmicrosoft.com" 
Customer 2 Website Domain: http://mycustomer2.com

=====
Customer 3 OIDC Domain: https://login.microsoftonline.com/customer3.onmicrosoft.com" 
Customer 3 Website Domain: http://mycustomer3.com

=====
My Company. Supporting all customers: https://login.microsoftonline.com/ourdomain.onmicrosoft.com" 
Website Domain: http://oursite.com

My goals are the following:

1. Create a single IdentityServer instance (sso.mycompany.com) that all customer websites will direct traffic to for authN
2. Be able to tell which domain referred the unauthenticated user to our SSO IDSERV instance and automatically redirect that user to their organizational sign in screen.
3. I am only using OIDC, not federated security
4. I do not want the user to see a list of external providers and have to choose which one they prefer to use. I would like to automatically redirect them to their organizational preferences that we have profiled in the client store.

This seems basic to me to implement with IDSERV3 as there are "external providers" that I might be able to use for this. I have done some research and read that I could potentially rewrite the OWIN pipeline dynamically per request as done at https://github.com/damianh/DynamicKatanaPipeline (originally discussed at: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1439) but I am unsure if this is the appropriate approach given the goals stated above.

Could someone explain or point me to a resource that could help me understand how I could accomplish something like this using IDSERV3?